# Oracle APEX interactive grid does not change when underlying materialized view changes

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have an interactive grid based on materialized view. Query is very simple `SELECT * FROM MY_MATERIALIZED_VIEW`. I added a few columns to the materialized view and refreshed it. Then I refreshed the APEX page but the new columns are not showing up. Is there something I am doing wrong or do I need to manually add those columns to the grid on APEX side and select the source as database column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it is the second option you mentioned. Apex uses the "old" materialized view definition for the page and is unaware of any changes you've made. It displays the old layout. However, it *would* break if you added a NOT NULL column and tried to save a newly added row to the current grid.

So, yes - you'll have to add those columns manually. Or, if the interactive grid is simple enough (i.e. you didn't do much changes), maybe it would be simpler to remove this region and create a new one using the wizard.

---

As Patrick commented (better to keep it here than in the comment), newest (18.x and above) Apex versions offer a nice option: **synchronize columns**, available in the context menu when right-clicking interactive grid's node. It will add newly added columns to the interactive grid so - you don't have to recreate the region.

Comment: In the left hand tree in Page Designer, open the context menu of your Interactive Grid region (right mouse click on the tree node) and pick 'Synchronize Columns'. It will add the new columns in Page Designer. No need to recreate the region.